# how to show asterisk sign before label start when label has fixed width

Tags: html, css

I want to show asterisk sign before my label indicating it is a mandatory field. following is my css id code for label,

```
#label{
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 73px;
}
```

output of above is,
*   Label
but I want it to be like,
  *Label
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use :before pseudo class

```
     .label:before{
     content:"*" ;
     color:red   
     }
```

Or

```
    #req:before{
    content:"*" ;
    color:red    
    }
​
```

**[DEMO Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/HCvAd/1/)**

Comment: thanks but what if I want to add this asterisk to only selected labels i.e <div class="label" id="req">txt</div>

Comment: I’d just like to add that `:before` is a CSS2 pseudo element, not a pseudo class. Also, as we are in 2017, CSS3 added double colons to distinguish pseudo elements from pseudo classes. Which means this is `::before` in CSS3. :o)

Answer (score 4):

```
Simple approach is like this
<font color="red">*</font>UserName<input type="text" name="userID"/>

It will display the asterik.
```

**Edit**

The **font** tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

[font link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp)

Comment: deprecated, should not use font anymore

Comment: @MohamadZein thanks.. was not knowing, font tag not supported in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the HTML it is difficult for us to know what is going on. I suspect you will be able to solve your problem using the little-known `white-space` property, if the asterisk is in the same element as #label. Try using `white-space: pre`.

Here is some more info:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp